# Whats the correct way of declaring folder path in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Need to know whats the correct way of declaring folder path , suppose I have a **dummy.py** file inside  a  main folder & also Inside main folder 2 child folders are present images & music , now if i want to declare a image22.img from images folder in **dummy.py** which one  is correct among the below two or both ae fine

```
myimage = "./images.image22.img"

or

myimage = "images.image22.img"  # without ./
```

had got this doubt as `os.path.abspath(myimage)` gives the same results for both

Comment: if images is folder then it is `images/image22.img` first `./` is useless

Comment: Please double check for typos "." vs "/".

Comment: its pretty much the same format as when you `cd` oe `ls` in your bash terminal

Comment: If the files/folders are in the same directory as your python script then you can just do images/filename.png, else you can always type the full path (not really recommended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of './' is not obligatory if you're requesting files from a folder that is on the current path.

So, in this example you don't need to use './' :

```
images/image22.img
```

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal's current working directory is `main`, then your path string should look like this.

```py
myimage = './images/image22.img'
#or
myimage = 'images/image22.img'
```